# How to get the most accurate volume of a special solid?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

The solid is defined by implicit function below:

$$\frac{51}{100} (\cos x \cos y+\cos x \cos z+\cos y \cos z)+\cos x+\cos y+\cos z+1\le0$$
where $x,y,z\in[0,2\pi]$

[image: plot]

I tried three different approaches with Mathematica to calculate the solid's volume:

1. **Monte Carlo :**

   ```
   ClearAll["Global`*"]; n = 1025; SeedRandom[20170524];

   f[x_] := (Cos /@ x // Total) +  51/100*Dot[Cos /@ RotateRight @ x, Cos /@ x] + 1

   Count[Flatten @ (f /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {n, 3}]), u_ /; u <= 0]/
     n*(2.0 Pi)^3
   ```
2. **immediate integral over implicit region:**

   ```
   NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ 
   ImplicitRegion[ 1 + Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] + 
       51/100 (Cos[x] Cos[y] + Cos[x] Cos[z] + Cos[y] Cos[z]) <= 0 && 
     0 <= x <= 2 Pi && 0 <= y <= 2 Pi && 0 <= z <= 2 Pi, {x, y, z}]]
   ```
3. **Boole integrand over cube**

   ```
   NIntegrate[
    Boole[1 + Cos[x] + Cos[y] + Cos[z] + 
       51/100 (Cos[x] Cos[y] + Cos[x] Cos[z] + Cos[y] Cos[z]) <= 0], {x, 
     0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, {z, 0, 2 Pi}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
   ```

Different approaches lead to different results.

Which one is more reliable and why since it seems there is no closed form result for this problem? Is it possible to evaluate the volume of this solid at arbitrary precision with Mathematica?

Comment: Your code for **1.  Monte Carlo** doesn't return any value (it apparently just defines an `f[x]`).

Comment: Is your second one copied correctly? Trying to run it in Mathematica gives me an error. The `{x,y,z}[Element]Implicit...` part looks incorrectly entered.

Comment: @QuantumDot It does if you add in the missing newlines the OP left out with their copying.

Comment: Updated. thanks

Comment: Consider simplifying the problem by shifting and then treating just one octant: `8 NIntegrate[Boole[1 - Cos[x] - Cos[y] - Cos[z] + 51 (Cos[x] Cos[y] + Cos[x] Cos[z] + Cos[y] Cos[z])/100 <= 0], {x, 0, π}, {y, 0, π}, {z, 0, π}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use symmetry, as J.M. suggested, split up the region....after some work....

```
8 (NIntegrate[1,
    {x, 0, ArcCos[-(49/100)]},
    {y, ArcCos[-((49 Cos[x])/(49 + 51 Cos[x]))], Pi},
    {z,
     Piecewise[{{ArcCos[(-100 - 100 Cos[x] - 100 Cos[y] - 
          51 Cos[x] Cos[y])/(
         100 + 51 Cos[x] + 51 Cos[y])], -1 <= (-100 - 100 Cos[x] - 
          100 Cos[y] - 51 Cos[x] Cos[y])/(
         100 + 51 Cos[x] + 51 Cos[y]) <= 1}}, 0],
     Pi}
    ] +
   NIntegrate[1,
    {x, ArcCos[-(49/100)], Pi},
    {y, 0, ArcCos[(-200 - 151 Cos[x])/(151 + 51 Cos[x])]},
    {z,
     ArcCos[(-100 - 100 Cos[x] - 100 Cos[y] - 51 Cos[x] Cos[y])/(
      100 + 51 Cos[x] + 51 Cos[y])],
     Pi}
    ] +
   NIntegrate[1,
    {x, ArcCos[-(49/100)], Pi},
    {y, ArcCos[(-200 - 151 Cos[x])/(151 + 51 Cos[x])], Pi},
    {z, 0, Pi}
    ])

(*  67.5935  *)
```

Comment: Thank you. But can you also indicate the `some work` mentioned? :D

Comment: @LCFactorization Solve for the intersections in terms of `Cos[z]`, then `Cos[y]` to determine the boundaries of the integration regions.  I used `Solve`, but `Reduce[inequality, {Cos[x], Cos[y], Cos[z]}]` might work.  It looks a little different, but there's probably more than one way.

Comment: `Reduce[inequality && -1 < Cos[x] < 1 && -1 < Cos[y] < 1 && -1 < Cos[z] < 1, {Cos[x], Cos[y], Cos[z]}]` give a better result for setting up the integrals.

Comment: I tried to increase the `WorkingPrecision`, and still got warning message like `The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more 
than 2000 times`. So this does not seem like a method assure numerical robustness. Am I right?

Comment: I use the multiple precision and double precision results comparison to determine whether the numerical method is robust.

Comment: @LCFactorization `Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}, WorkingPrecision -> 20` yields ``67.59353836486477145961457284250657132954`20.``, which agrees with the machine precision result to about 8 digits. After several minutes, ``Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}, WorkingPrecision -> 24`` yields ``67.59353836486223222953151386376534048904`24.``, which agrees with the 20-digit result to 13 digits.  The default method is much faster, but not as accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't have to use Monte Carlo of which the confidence interval determination becomes another headache! BTW, I am already considering the inverse divergence theorem and converting it into surface integrals.